# How to flatten an array inside of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, flatten

Basically, I want to flatten an array inside of an object with Javascript (preferably ES6). I'm actually not sure if this is even an issue of flattening, I just want a good way to make this change.

I want to go from this:

```
{
  id: "123",
  name: "test",
  history: [
    {
      id: "456",
      name: "test2"
    },
    {
      id: "789",
      name: "test3"
    }
  ]
}
```

To this...

```
{
  id: "123",
  name: "test"
},
{
  id: "456",
  name: "test2"
},
{
  id: "789",
  name: "test3"
}
```

Essentially in the original object, I have a "history" property that related to that specific object. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please include your attempt at solving this?

Comment: That resultant structure isn't valid

Comment: Can the objects in `history` have `history` arrays themselves? In other words, can this be infinitely nested?

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructuring and rest syntax, to separate history and the 1st object, and then combine them to a single array with spread or concat.

```js
const { history, ...obj1 } = {"id":"123","name":"test","history":[{"id":"456","name":"test2"},{"id":"789","name":"test3"}]}

const result = [obj1, ...history]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
 const data =  {
  "id": "123",
  "name": "test",
  "history": [
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "test2"
    },
    {
      "id": "789",
      "name": "test3"
    }
  ]
}

const  {id, name, history} =  data ;
const result  = [{id, name} , ...history];

console.log(result);
```